# EF query readonly Iqueryable

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, iqueryable

I have tens of different views and on some, the data that comes from database, must be manipulated before shown to user.

for example:

```
var students = _repository.Students.Select(c => { c.StartDate = FixDateToCurrentYear(c.StartDate ); c.EndDate = FixDateToCurrentYear(c.EndDate); return c; }).ToList();
```

So basically I now have a variable, where `Students` `StartDate` and `EndDate` have been **fixed** by some logic, which is not relevant at the moment.

The problem here is that, whenever somewhere a SaveChanges() function is called, then the changed dates for students are also persisted to database.

I only want to use the changed dates for the logic in specific view. How could I handle this?

I have heard about `.AsNoTracking();` but this must be put directly to DbSet item, but I want to handle it on controller side, is it possible?

Comment: *I have heard about .AsNoTracking(); but this must be put directly to DbSet item* Do you mean it's an extension method on `DbSet`? Because it does not seem to be (disclaimer: EF 5) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679169(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Are you saying that AsNoTracking should also be on IQueryable? For some reason it is not shown for me. But this one is shown for my DbSet http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696268(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn237199(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pull the students from the db first and the do a select to an anonymous type. EF won't know how to track changes on that.

```
var students = 
    _repository.Students.ToList()
               .Select(s => 
                   new { StartDate = FixDateToCurrentYear(c.StartDate),
                         EndDate = FixDateToCurrentYear(c.EndDate),
                         Student = s });
```

Comment: Actually there are more fields that need to be queries from Students, around 20, and doing this everywhere for 2 dates seems quite an overhead.

Comment: Select the two dates together with the entire student object into the new anonymous object.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest thing I can think of is to perform your fix at the point you display it to the user, e.g. in Razor:

```
@FixDateToCurrentYear(student.StartDate)
```

In this way, you're not actually changing the value, you're just changing how it's displayed.

If you need to do more than display, you will need to create a partial buddy class, add a new property and modify its get method:

```
public partial class Student
{
    DateTime StartDateComputed {
        get
        {
            return  FixDateToCurrentYear(StartDate);
        }
        set;
    }
}
```

Now, use StartDateComputed instead of StartDate and the same for EndDate.

Comment: Actually it is not only about display, but there are 100 lines of calculations, that are based on those dates.